# Copying files across network from a specific folder of different network hosts to a common network destination using batch file

Tags: networking, batch-file

I'm trying to automate a manual work of copying a specific file from many network client machines.
All clients will have a file that have to be backed up from time to time.
for that i have a list of client hostnames. and the file to be backed up is in a shared folder of each host.
Now I want a batch file that creates a new folder with "dd-mm-yyyy"format and copies all the files in to a masterHost.
for that i have wrote

```
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%
echo New folder name %date%
MKDIR \\MasterHost\d$\%date%
copy \\client1\c$\data\data.txt \\MasterHost\d$\%date%\client1data.txt
copy \\client2\c$\data\data.txt \\MasterHost\d$\%date%\client2data.txt
copy \\client3\c$\data\data.txt \\MasterHost\d$\%date%\client3data.txt
copy \\client4\c$\data\data.txt \\MasterHost\d$\%date%\client4data.txt
copy \\client5\c$\data\data.txt \\MasterHost\d$\%date%\client5data.txt
```

now can anyone help me getting the client name from a file that has list of client hostnames say hostList.txt because i dont want to manually enter the host names each time...

the hostList.txt will look like this

```
client1
client2
client3
client4
client5
.
.
.
etc
```

Even a small help will be appreciated because i'm new to batch scripting. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
for /F %x in ('type hostList.txt') do ( 
   copy \\%x\c$\data\data.txt \\MasterHost\d$\%date%\client1data.txt
)
```

instead of all the copy... lines.

Comment: Add an extra `%` to the `%x` loop variables for use in a batch file.  Make them `%%x`